# Unable to open primary script (Permission denied)

Tags: docker, nginx, laravel-5, synology

I Have:

```
+------+                                                         +-------------+
|      +NIC1 (192.168.1.100) <--> Router <--> (192.168.1.2) NIC1 +             |
|  PC  |                                                         |     DSM     |
|      +NIC2 (10.10.0.100) <--Peer-2-Peer---> (10.10.0.2)   NIC2 +             |
+------+                                                         | [4xDOCKERs] |
                                                                 |(172.17.0.x) |
                                                                 +-------------+
```

*I'm following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@shakyShane/laravel-docker-part-1-setup-for-development-e3daaefaf3c

the tutorial will guide you to build 3 Docker Containers:

1. Web (NGINX)
2. App (Laravel)
3. DB (MySQL)

my docker compose:

```
version: '2'

services:

  # The Application
  app:
    network_mode: bridge
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: app.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes:
      - /volume3/homes/my.name/www/:/var/www
    environment:
      - "DB_PORT=3306"
      - "DB_HOST=database"

  # The Web Server
  web:
    network_mode: bridge
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www
    volumes_from:
      - app
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    links:
      - app
    depends_on:
      - app

  # The Database
  database:
    network_mode: bridge
    image: mysql:5.6
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_USER=homestead"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret"
    ports:
      - "33061:3306"

volumes:
  dbdata:
```

app.dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2.6-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
  mysql-client libmagickwand-dev --no-install-recommends \
  && pecl install imagick \
  && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1 \
  && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt \
  && docker-php-ext-enable imagick \
  && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
```

web.dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.10

ADD vhost.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

vhost.conf:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  index index.php index.html;
  root /var/www/public;

  location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass app:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  }
}
```

Result when i tried to access the web from my pc with url http://10.10.0.2:8080 :

in browser:

> Access denied.

app Log:

> 172.17.0.5 -  09/Jun/2018:17:24:18 +0000 "GET /index.php" 403                                          [09-Jun-2018 17:24:18] WARNING: [pool www] child 8 said into stderr:
>   "ERROR: Unable to open primary sc ript: /var/www/public/index.php
>   (Permission denied)"

Web Log:

> 2018/06/09 17:23:18 [error] 7#7: *3 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to
>   open primary script: /var/www/p ublic/index.php (Permission denied)"
>   while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, 
>   server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://172.17.0.4:9000", host: "10.10.0.2:8080"
>   172.17.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2018:17:23:18 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 25 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;  Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.79 Safari/537.36" "-"
>   172.17.0.1 - - [09/Jun/2018:17:23:18 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 403 571 "http://10.10.0.2:8080 /" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
>   10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396. 79 Safari/537.36" "-"
>   2018/06/09 17:23:18 [error] 7#7: *3 open()
>   "/var/www/public/favicon.ico" failed (13: Permission denied ), client:
>   172.17.0.1, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "10.10.0.2:8080", referre r: "http://10.10.0.2:8080/"

anything that i missed here? why I can't access the web from my pc?

Comment: so I mange to get it work by allowing "everyone" read and write - however, I dont understand, "who" (which user) is actually accessing, so I could just let her access (instead of allowing everyone)

Comment: You could run ps aux to see what user is running php-fpm. I'm having a similar issue in a docker container as well. php-fpm is getting a 404 on the index.php file, even though nginx has access and both should be running as www-data.

Answer (score 0):

Add in your web dockerfile :

```
RUN chmod -R 600  /var/www

RUN addgroup myuser && \
    adduser -D -h /var/www myuser -G myuser

RUN chown -R myuser:myuser /var/www

USER myuser
```